# Причастный оборот [3]

Tags: причастный-оборот

Доброго времени суток!
У меня с товарищем вышел спор, виновником которого стал следующий кусок текста:
"Пуштуны - иранский народ, населяющий в основном юго-восток, юг и юго-запад Афганистана и северо-запад Пакистана, основными отличительными характеристиками которого служат восточноиранский язык пашто, традиции номадизма, кодекс чести Пуштунвалай и разветвлённая родо-племенная структура".
Мне кажется, что предложение звучит криво - у читателя может возникнуть вопрос "А чьими отличительными характеристиками, пуштунов или Пакистана?". На мой взгляд, гораздо лучше было бы написать так: "Пуштуны - иранский народ, населяющий в основном юго-восток, юг и юго-запад Афганистана и северо-запад Пакистана. Его отличительными характеристиками служат...".
Так в каком же случае предложение построено более гармонично?
Спасибо.

Comment: Ваш  вариант  правильней.

Answer (score 2):

1) Предложение,  действительно, сложно воспринимать как на слух, так и в записи.

2) Если  общая структура текста позволяет, то для лучшего понимания смысла сообщения его можно разделить на два  (предложенный вариант). В то же время такое деление может нарушить динамику  построения текста.

3) Если автор сообщения  не хочет делить  его на две части /два предложения, то можно предложить следующий вариант:

"Пуштуны - иранский народ, КОТОРЫЙ населяет в основном юго-восток, юг и юго-запад Афганистана и северо-запад Пакистана и основными отличительными характеристиками КОТОРОГО служат восточноиранский язык пашто, традиции номадизма, кодекс чести Пуштунвалай и разветвлённая родоплеменная структура".

В этом  случае местоимение «который» служит своеобразной меткой для каждой части предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Согласна с Софией. Удачно составлена фраза со словами-метками "который" - "которого". Иначе получаются отличительные особенности Пакистана.

Либо - первая часть остается "народ, населяющий...". И после точки повторяете слово народ: "Отличительной особенностью этого народа..." или вторая часть все же про Пакистан?

Answer (score 0):

> "Пуштуны - иранский народ, населяющий в основном юго-восток, юг и юго-запад Афганистана и северо-запад Пакистана. Его отличительными характеристиками служат...".

Тот же самый вопрос: *его* - это народа или Пакистана?

Comment: Здесь уже будет прочитываться  структура текста. (1)Пуштуны - это народ... (2)Отличительной особенностью  этого народа служат..